# What's the difference between textmate scopes and semantic token type?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

the confusing example

[image: img]

I'm creating a theme for vscode. However I'm confused about the two different scope descriptions: textmate scopes and semantic token type.

Why is the foreground in textmate scopes crossed out?

I want the text mate foreground color to be applied, not crossed out.

Comment: if you don't want semantic highlighting you can disable it in your settings